# Error with facebook login in mobile browser

Tags: oauth

I am trying to login by Facebook using `react-facebook-login`.
I logged successfully in the web browser but not in the mobile browser.

**Error:**

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: The error message could not be any more explicit or clear...

Comment: I'm having the same problem even though I've whitelisted my redirect URI. Any progress on this?

Answer (score 4):

Set in props: `isMobile={false}`

source: https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/257
by: alen12345

try that it worked for me.

Comment: thank Dharman, i wont do that mistake again at least now i`ve learnt it.

Answer (score 0):

> You might try running your website through the Facebook Debugger:
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?ref=u2u
>
> This tool was built to help to identify any errors that Facebook is
>   reading from your website, and help provide information on what needs
>   to be fixed to unblock your link.
>
> From there, you can get help [...] from the Facebook Developers team to make
>   your website compliant and help our [facebook] systems detect it as safe.
>   Click the link below and select "Get Started" to open a support ticket
>   with the Facebook Developers team (this option may not be available
>   for all websites):
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/?ref=u2u

source: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1278521772201326

Answer (score 0):

Try different browser for Mobile.I think mobile browser is caching your url or some of your react is not browser compatible.
Use chrome Developer tools and emulate it for different phones.
It may be script issue .

You need to add all URI in whitelisted fied for you Facebook App
Facebook Developers -> Settings -> Advanced -> Security
In Security block you will see 'IP allowed server'
Add all URI in this field

Answer (score 0):

Try disableMobileRedirect={true} in the props of Facebook Login:

```
<FacebookLogin
  {...other props}
  disableMobileRedirect={true}
/>
```